# Why does Swift insist on this being an optional?

Tags: swift

Caveat: I've been coding in Swift for about 2 days!

I am following along with some simple tutorials to build a status menu application. The following is a reduction of my AppDelegate.swift class:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-2)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let icon = NSImage(named: "StatusBarImage")
        icon?.setTemplate(true)
    }
}
```

My question is, why does Xcode insist that my `icon` constant be an optional (it was also OK with me forcing it to be unwrapped). The tutorial didn't show that the `?` was needed, but Xcode shows me the following error if I leave it out:

```
Value of optional type 'NSImage' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

(I'm using Xcode 6.4, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: you can use `let icon = NSImage(named: "StatusBarImage")!` as well, to force it unwrap, not checking it's `nil` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed:):

**Declaration:**

```
init?(named name: String) -> NSImage
```

Which means by default it's initialiser is an optional.

**Return Value**

> The NSImage object associated with the specified name or nil if no
>   such image was found.

**Discussion**

> The NSImage class may cache a reference to the returned image object
>   for performance in some cases. However, the class holds onto cached
>   objects only while the object exists. If all strong references to the
>   image are subsequently removed, the object may be quietly removed from
>   the cache. Thus, if you plan to hold onto a returned image object, you
>   must maintain a strong reference to it like you would any Cocoa
>   object. You can clear an image object from the cache explicitly by
>   calling the object’s setName: method and specifying nil for the image
>   name.

That's why it is asking you `did you mean to use '!' or '?'`

So if you use `!` that means you are unwrapping optional value and if you use `?` compiler will consider it as optional.

Comment: If you use `!` it becomes an _explicitly unwrapped optional_.

Answer (score 1):

Because image named **StatusBarImage** might as well not be in the assets and it would result in bad access exception.

Comment: This makes sense. The tutorial didn't specify it as an optional, but I'm guessing he was on an earlier version of Swift. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually Xcode is not forcing anything : if you check the NSImage documentation you will see that the NSImage initializer is a **failable initializer**.

Like @FruitAddict said the whole point of those initializers is to fail gracefully (by returning an optional with a nil value) when the object could not be created.  [Check Apple Developer Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17)

Answer (score 0):

By adding ! or this ? You know explicitly that imageNamed can returned you a nil.

And Compiler just makes sure that you know about it.